# Excessively hot window frames

Tags: styrofoam

I live in Arizona.  The frames on the windows that face west get extremely hot inside the house.  I have sun screens installed and the aluminum frame touches the exterior window frame thus transferring all the heat.   To avoid replacing the window I’m considering installing 1/2 inch foam board on top of the window frame and set the screen over that.  Seems it should help reduce the heat transfer and I can cover the entire frame with the foam.  Has anyone tried this or seen stories of those who have?  Appreciate any insight.

Comment: Choose a foil faced foam product, probably, to survive the sun exposure. There will still be heat transfer but this should reduce the transfer by conduction, at least. Shade spaced away from the window (and house) would be best  if you could arrange it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   Are you suggesting add a spacer to separate the window frame from the sunscreen and forget the idea of foam between the two?

Comment: Btw, today I slipped cardboard  between the window frame and sunscreen in one corner.  It seems it did help but of course the frame that was not isolated will transfer heat across the entire frame.  I just wanted to get some idea if it would help.  By adding the foam board I’m hopeful it helps with condition from the screen and convection if I cover all surface area of the frame.

Comment: Conduction from the screen

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that if you can arrange for some souce of shade which is physically separated from the house (awning, plant (difficult in many parts of AZ) fence, etc...) it will more effectivly reduce heat ingress .vs. a hot screen over the window. Insulating the screen from the window frame is good. Having a properly thermal designed window frame that did not easily conduct from outside to inside would be better, but involves replacing windows and is likely beyond scope for now. Providing shade 3 or 6 or 12 feet away would be better yet, if possible. It may not be possible.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you.  Totally agree just not an option on this prperty